# Activity lifetime - importance of the declaration sequence

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

Does it change anything to write :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    MydbHandler.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Or

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    MydbHandler.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general recommendation is:

- For lifecycle methods with clear "creation" semantics (e.g., `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`), chain to the superclass first
- For lifecycle methods with clear "destruction" semantics (e.g., `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroy()`), chain to the superclass last, after any of your work
- For everything else, it hopefully does not matter unless documented otherwise

Hence, it's generally better form to use your first snippet. That being said, I am not aware of any actual problem with your second snippet -- in fact, I used that same approach for my first couple of years of Android development.

Answer (score 2):

No, in this case there is no difference.

You can checkout the source code for [Activity.onDestroy()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onDestroy%28%29) (from grepcode.com). You'll see that onDestroy() simply closes all managed Dialogs, managed Cursor and closes the SearchManager (if opened).

Comment: Thx I was not aware where to dig into the code, which certainly helps.

Comment: You can [download the source code](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) for yourself, but be careful it's up to 8.5GB nowadays.